# CUSTOM FILTERS не переведены

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

С появлением новых пользовательских фильтров фраза "CUSTOM FILTERS" не переведена.

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: О! А то бы я даже не узнал, что такое появилось)

Comment: Уже перевели, похоже